# unir variables y compararlas con alamcenada en bd jquery-ajax-php-

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hola a todos espero estén muy bien, ojala me puedan ayudar tengo en mi base de datos un campo que almacena el valor de estos tres campos juntos por ejemplo:

campo 1 llamado manzana: 2
campo 2 llamado ubicacion: 3
campo 3 llamado Horizontal: 0

Al tomar el valor de los tres campos se almacena en la base de datos asi

code: 230

este es el codigo del formulario que uso:

```
<input name="manzana" type="text" id="manzana" size="5"/>
<input name="ubicacion" type="text" id="ubicacion" size="5"/>
<input name="horizontal" type="text" id="horizontal" size="5"/>
```

ahora en el script que hace la "magia" para recoger los valores agregados en cada campo es este... y enviarlos a un php para verificar si existe en la base de datos un valor igual almacenado y mostrar una alerta que ya existe un valor igual almacenado.

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<link href="css.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#horizontal').blur(function(){
        $('#Info3').html('<img src="" alt="" />').fadeOut(1000);
        var valManzana = $(this).val();
        var valUbicacion = $(this).val();
        var valHorizontal = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "check_manzana_availablity.php",
            data: {manzana: valManzana, ubicacion: valUbicacion, horizontal: valHorizontal},
           // success: function(data) {
               success: function(data) {
                if(data!="") {
                    //------------------------------------------------
                    $("#button").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                } else {
                   <!------ $("#nic").removeAttr("disabled");-------->
                    $("#button").removeAttr("disabled");
                }
 
                $('#Info3').fadeIn(1000).html(data);
                //alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

me viene la primera pregunta) para que el blur (linea 5) este evaluando lo que se agrega en cada campo (al ir escribiendo) como lo pongo (en este ejemplo lo puse solo en el campo con nombre horizontal) como hago para modificar que haga el blur (linea 5) en cada uno de ellos no se si me explico..

ya puse el código como me lo indican a continuación... el cual debe enviar al php los valores de los campos y en tiempo real evaluar que code de la base de datos no concuerde con lo agregado en los tres campos.. (lo cual uno en el php: check_manzana_availablity.php)

a continuacion pongo el script php que hace el "truco" para que la magia sea completa.... pero no me sirve aun.... que hago mal

```
<?php
sleep(1);
//------------------------
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_SERVER_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_SERVER_PASSWORD', 'contrasena');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'basededatos');
$conexion = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_SERVER_USERNAME, DB_SERVER_PASSWORD);
mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE, $conexion);
//----------------------------
if($_REQUEST)
{
// recibo las variables---------------------------------------------
   $manzana2 = $_REQUEST['manzana'];
   $ubicacion2 = $_REQUEST['ubicacion'];
   $horizontal2 = $_REQUEST['horizontal'];
//uno las variables ----------------------------------------------------
   $todo=$manzana2.$ubicacion2.$horizontal2;
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   $query3 = "SELECT * FROM catastro WHERE code = '$todo'";
   $results3 = mysql_query($query3) or die('ok');
    if(!empty($manzana2)){
   if(mysql_num_rows(@$results3) > 0)
   {
      echo '<div id="Error"></div>';
      echo "<script type=''>alert('Ya existe');</script>";
    }else{
      echo "";
   }
   }
}
?>
```

en el script js si envio las variables bien para que el php las recoja?
en el php si nombro bien las variables y se concatenas para formar el código a evaluar?
que me falta para que todo funcione....

necesito ayuda por favor!!!!

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende. ¿Qué debería hacer el código y qué hace ahora? ¿Qué problemas o errores tienes? Por otra parte, lo que tú llamas *magia* puede ser no tan mágico, sino un grave problema de diseño. ¿Qué justifica que debas guardar valores combinados en una columna?

Comment: lo que hace ese código es comprobar que no exista en la base de datos un valor igual al que se intenta agregar el resultado sale sin enviar el script liveaction!!! lo que puse son partes del codigo lo que hacen todo... mil gracias por responder amigo!!!

Comment: Es que no se entiende. Por favor pulsa en [edit] y explica con claridad el problema. Mientras más claro seas planteando tu problema más rápido podremos ayudarte.

Comment: no se entiende??? si esta bien explicado.. se recoge de 3 campos un valor en cada uno que unido los tres valores da uno solo por ejemplo en el campo 1 el numero 2 en el campo 2 el valor: 0 y en el campo 3 el valor 2 la suma de estos números da por ejemplo 203 pues se concatenan el valor de los campos... luego el script recoge esos valores y los comprueba en la base de datos si existe un valor igual y si es asi bloquea el botón enviar... mas bien eres de esos que les gusta llenar respuestas ;) bromeo!! jejejjejejeje saludos

Comment: @Eduardo preguntas "*unir variables y compararlas*", pero en el contenido hablas del evento `blur` para modificar, explica mejor la pregunta. ¿Que es lo que quieres realmente?

Comment: Hola Juan Rivera.. gracias por responder... pues te cuento existe un valor en una base de datos ejemplo el numero 256... por otro lado existe un formulario el cual tiene entre todos sus campos 3 campos por separado que recogen un numero por ejemplo campo1=2; campo2=5; campo3= 6 la unión de los valores de cada campo da campo1+campo2+campo3= 256 hasta alli todo claro cierto!!!! (continua debajo..)

Comment: pues bien ahora tomo ese valor (256)  que es la unión de los campos arriba mencionados y con el codigo ese jquery ajax lo llevo a un archivo php el cual compara al instante si ese numero 256 ya existe en la tabla.. y si es asi me muestra una alerta indicandolo..  alli puse los codigos... (continua debajo..)

Comment: el ejemplo me funciona solo si uso un solo campo el cual puedes ver en funcionamiento aquí: http://serviaseo.net.co/catastro/formularioin.php si colocan por ejemplo el numero de Formato 0004 salta una alerta debido a que ya existe un formato con ese numero... ahora lo que deseo es usarlo pero en los campos Manzana,  Ubicación y Horizontal.. ya!!!